# Linux: where to find the "segments retransmited" from /proc?

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

We can use `"netstat -s"` to query `"segments retransmitted"`. But:

1) Where does the original data from? /proc? Looks like  `/proc/net/netstat` includes other retransmit counters but no `"segments retransmitted"`.

2) How do I get this programmatically by C?

Thanks!

```
lisa@ubuntuClient:~/logs# netstat -s | grep trans
    479025 segments retransmited
    TCPLostRetransmit: 4934
    252476 fast retransmits
    103 forward retransmits
    77435 retransmits in slow start
    668 SACK retransmits failed
    TCPRetransFail: 44
    TCPSynRetrans: 2250
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `netstat` trace:

```
open("/proc/net/snmp", O_RDONLY)        = 3
```

These values come from `/proc/net/snmp`.

Regarding to how to access these values programmatically [in C or any other language], I think `netstat` can answer that question: read the file and parse its contents :).

**Notes:**

`netstat` v1.42, `net-tools` 1.60